# Transform a multiple line url request into a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, request

I try to download a serie of text files from different websites. I am using `urllib.request` with Python. I want to expend the list of URL without making the code long.

The working sequence is

```
import urllib.request

url01 = 'https://web.site.com/this.txt'
url02 = 'https://web.site.com/kind.txt'
url03 = 'https://web.site.com/of.txt'
url04 = 'https://web.site.com/link.txt'
[...] 

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url01, "Liste n°01.txt")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url02, "Liste n°02.txt")
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url03, "Liste n°03.txt")
[...]
```

The number of file to download is increasing and I want to keep the second part of the code short.

I tried

```
 i = 0
 while i<51
   i = i +1
   urllib.request.urlretrieve( i , "Liste n°0+"i"+.txt")
```

It doesn't work and I am thinking that a while loop can be use for string but not for request.

So I was thinking of making it a function.

```
def newfunction(i)
return urllib.request.urlretrieve(url"i", "Liste n°0"+1+".txt")
```

But it seem that I am missing a big chunk of it.
This request is working but it seem I cannot transform it for long list or URL.

Answer (score 0):

As a general suggestion, I'd recommend the `requests` module for Python, rather than `urllib`.

Based on that, some naive code for a possible function:

```py
import requests

def get_file(site, filename):
    target = site + "/" + filename
    try: 
        r = requests.get(target, allow_redirects=True)
        open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
        return r.status_code
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("File not downloaded, error: {}".format(e))
```

You can then call the function, passing in parameters of site and file name:

```py
get_file('https://web.site.com', 'this.txt')
```

The function will raise an exception, but not stop execution, if it cannot download a file. You could expand exception handling to deal with files not being writable, but this should be a start.

Comment: Hello Mike, your code is indeed working better than the urllib one I made. It manage to even download some txt file that wasn't loading with the previous script. 
Thank you very much Mike.

I had to install "requests" from the powershell and "Wheel" which wasn't. I also had to change the target part to be only [target = site].

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you're not casting the variable i to an integer before your concatenating it to the url string. That may be the reason why you're code isn't working. The while-loop/for-loop approach shouldn't effect whether or not the requests get sent out. I recommend using the requests module for making requests as well. Mike's post covers what the function should kind of look like. I also recommend creating a sessions object if you're going to be making a whole lot of requests in a piece of code. The sessions object will keep the underlying TCP connection open while you make your requests, which should reduce latency, CPU usage, and network congestion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection#Advantages). The code would look something like this:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    for i in range(10):
        s.get(str(i)+'.com')  # make request
       # write to file here
```

To cast to a string you would want something like this:

```
 i = 0
 while i<51
   i = i +1
   urllib.request.urlretrieve( i , "Liste n°0" + str(i) + ".txt")
```